# Flutter_I have a question about rotate canvas

Tags: flutter

I am drawing shapes using `canvas` and `customPaint` as shown in the image below.
And I'm going to drag each shape to rotate it.

I knew that I could rotate it through the `canvas.rotate`.
But if I use this, there's a problem with all the shapes rotating the same.

The following is part of my code.

```
class Shape {}
class Rectangle extends Shape {
  Rect? rect;
  double? left, top;
  bool? isRectSelected;

  final paint = Paint();

  Rectangle(Color color, double width) {
    this.paint
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = width
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke; // no fill
  }

// ========================

class Sketcher extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Shape> shapes;

  Sketcher(
    this.shapes,
  ) : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var shape in shapes) {
      if (shape is Rectangle) {    
        final degrees = 30; // angle
        final radians = degrees * math.pi / 180;

        // ! If use it, all shape rotate same angle
        canvas.translate(shape.rect!.left, shape.rect!.top); // left top 
        canvas.rotate(radians); 
        canvas.translate(-shape.rect!.left, -shape.rect!.top);

        // ractangle shape
        canvas.drawRect(shape.rect!, shape.paint);
      }

    // same code circle...
    }
  }
```

[image]

How do I rotate each shape instead of the entire canvas?
Could you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [canvas.save()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/save.html) to save the state the canvas then adjust the canvas according to your need and then use [canvas.restore()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/restore.html) to restore the canvas to the state before save(). The action inside the save-restore action will still be draw to the canvas.

```
canvas.save();
// do something
// canvas.rotate(radians);
// canvas.drawRect();  // this rect will be rotated
canvas.restore();

canvas.drawRect();  // this rect will not be rotated
```